# Enetrprise wsdl only for login and security

Tags: webservices, security

I exposed an apex class to an external system from salesforce, I read that I have to give the external system custom wsdl and enterprise wsdl. can I provide the enterprise wsdl to an external system by blocking the use of bees other than login? I have to ensure that the external system uses the enterprise wsdl only for login and absolutely must not access the data.I read that I have to use profiles and permissions. I created a new user and a new profile and without any special configuration with soap ui I can use the custom ws that creates records. should not I have received an error?

Comment: How did you expose the apex class to the external system, and does this system have its own profile and user with a Salesforce License?

Comment: Don't forget to enable your apex class for this profile. Also make sure you gave all necessary object and field permission and it will work

Comment: Right, the ability to create records is controlled by what permissions that user has. If you remove the create permission for that object from the profile (and permissions sets, etc.), you should get an error when you use that system to try to create a record for that object.

Comment: my problem is that I'm forced to give to ext sys the enterprise wsdl and potentially has access to the data with this. is it a way to block the use of the login and the custom ws? I find this story of providing all the enterprise very troubling and I do not know how to guarantee data protection. and the proper functioning of the custom ws invoked with a new profile for which I have not configured anything terrifies me

Comment: I would like lock all api in wsdl enterprise to external system and enable only login method. With my ws i can control its operation but with api no. What can i do To guarantee security?the external system could get data because it has the enterprise wsdl I'm forced to give it for login

Comment: Then you can try Rest oauth login.